# Parsing httpClient result in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've tried without success to parse observable result in ionic 3.

Here is my code for the provider "sncf.ts" :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

interface Results{
    places: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class SncfProvider {
    private BASE_URL: String;
    private options : any;
    temp:any;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.BASE_URL = 'https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf';
        this.options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'mytoken') };
    }

    getPlaces(place){
        return this.http.get<Results>(this.BASE_URL+'/places?q='+place, this.options)
          .subscribe((data: Results)=>{
            resolve(data.places);
          });
    }

}
```

I've got an error :

```
Argument of type '(data: Results) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: HttpEvent<Results>) => void'. Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'HttpEvent<Results>' is not assignable to type 'Results'. Type 'HttpProgressEvent' is not assignable to type 'Results'. Property 'places' is missing in type 'HttpProgressEvent'.
```

I've tried Promise too but it still doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to type the response in more than one place with http client.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

interface Results{
    places: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class SncfProvider {
    private BASE_URL: String;
    private options : any;
    temp:any;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.BASE_URL = 'https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf';
        this.options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'mytoken') };
    }

    getPlaces(place){
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL+'/places?q='+place, this.options)
          .subscribe(data =>{
            return <Results>resolve(data.places); //why resolve??
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: A type assertion `subscribe(data => {results = <Results>data; resolve(data.places);})` would be better. Annotating the type of the parameter is also bad since it acts like a hidden type assertion.

Comment: that is better (type-wise) but I think what you had made more sense otherwise. Returning from `subscribe` doesn't make sense nor does applying the type assertion to the result of `resolve`, it should be applied to `data`. Also, as you say, "why resolve??", it is far from clear.